# ExpressionEngine: Adding BrilliantRetail members into Campaign Monitor using Campaigner

Tags: plugins, module, content-management-system, hook, expressionengine

I have an [ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/) store. I use [BrilliantRetail](http://www.brilliantretail.com/) for the store. A person can register through a form or be automatically registered when the buy a product. I'm using [Campaigner](http://experienceinternet.co.uk/software/campaigner/) to automatically put members into a specific mailing list on [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/). I can't get these to all play nice together:

I've confirmed that a member is automatically going into Campaign Monitor when I register through the EE backend.

I've confirmed the member flow works in BrilliantRetail.

Does anyone have any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Sorry to revive an old question, but did you ever get these 2 plugins working together? I've got everything configured according to Campaigner docs and I manually added a select dropdown with the "yes" and "no" options into the Brilliant Retail registration template using the name of the custom member field I added, but for some reason the subscriptions aren't coming through.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have SQL access via phpMyAdmin or similar? Because the first thing to look at is extension priority, in the exp_extensions table. Check if BR and Campaigner are using any of the same hooks; if so, make sure that BR has a LOWER number in the 'priority' column.

Comment: Yea, thats what I was thinking too. I looked in that table and BR isn't an extension. It's a module.